# pyodbc ImportError DLL load failed while executing script but able to import in console using python interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.7, pyodbc

I have tried this with both 64 bit and 32 bit python and here are the errors i get for both versions

64 bit - ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

32 bit - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Strange part is that when I try to import pyodbc in console using python interpreter, i am able to import it without any issues.

[image: no error interpreter]

[image: error while executing script]

I am running this on Windows 10. I have been able to use pyodbc on windows 7 64 bit and upgraded to Windows 10 a while back and have been facing this issue since.

This is the only code I am running to test the import statement using a virtual environment

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
import pyodbc
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using which gives the error, and how you are running it (please include text, not pictures).

Comment: @mkrieger1 - Thank you for responding. I have updated the question with the code snippet I am using to test

Comment: Ah, so now you reveal that you run the code in a virtual environment. This could be the difference which explains why the one works but the other one doesn't. But you don't provide any details, so we can't tell.

Comment: I am running the script and the interepreter using python from the same virtual environment. I tried it without the virtual environment as well and the result was same. I have checked the path of python being used in the script and can confirm that it is using the intended python installation.